# Can I generate numbers in series using IntegerField in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I have created a model where Integer field is among the field in my model, when each post is added I want to have number that will be generated in series in each post. Can I achieve by just using Integer field, Please help!!!

models.py

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    docs_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Jina la Nyaraka")

    item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100,verbose_name="Aina ya nyaraka" )

    police_station = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Kituo cha polisi")

    phone_no = models.CharField(verbose_name="Namba yako ya simu", max_length=10, blank=False, 
validators=[int_list_validator(sep=''),MinLengthValidator(10),])

    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,verbose_name="Date")

    Description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name="Maelezo zaidi")

    pay_no = models.IntegerField(default=0,verbose_name="Namba ya malipo")

    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Documents",blank=False, verbose_name="Picha ya nyaraka")

    """docstring for Documents"""
    def __str__(self):
        return self.docs_name
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def PostNew(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('loststuffapp:IndexView')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'loststuffapp/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

well as far i can get it, you need to make some kind of sequence for your IntegerField.
while it's not and id field, you can emmulate it by taking max value of that field among all objects:

```
max_val = YourModelClass.objects.all().aggregate(Max('that_field_in_question'))
# then just make new object, and assign max+1 to 'that_field_in_question'
new_obj = YourModelClass('that_field_in_question'=max_val + 1)
new_obj.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have added model.py and views.py  above if you can clarify more from there. please help!!

Comment: are you sure, class Documents represents data you fill in on your form page? It doesn't have .author field.

Comment: Yes documents represent data in my form page, about author field it works fine even  I have not added it in models, if I remove author in my views it doesn't work

Comment: if the field is not in the model, it won't be saved to DB. It also needs number field if you need to store it

Comment: It works fine I can store it in database. If I remove it doesn't work, I don't know how, I copied it from somewhere